# merge json data with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I got a JSON file like this.
**i need to merge the name and value from the same certname.**

What is the best way to do this with javascript?

```
    [
        {
          certname: 'server1',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'clientcert',
          value: 'server1'
        },
        {
          certname: 'server2',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'clientcert',
          value: 'server2'
        },
        {
          certname: 'server3',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'clientcert',
          value: 'server3'
        }
    ],
    ]    
        {
          certname: 'server1',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'operatingsystem',
          value: 'windows'
        },
        {
          certname: 'server2',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'operatingsystem',
          value: 'windows'
        },
        {
          certname: 'server3',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'operatingsystem',
          value: 'RedHat'
        }
   ],
   [
        {
          certname: 'server1',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',
          value: '2008 R2'
        },
        {
          certname: 'server2',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',
          value: '2008 R2'
        },
        {
          certname: 'server3',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',
          value: '6'
        }
    ],
    [
        {
          certname: 'server1',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'clientversion',
          value: '5.5.2'
        },
        {
          certname: 'server2',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'clientversion',
          value: '5.5.2'
        },
        {
          certname: 'server3',
          environment: 'acceptance',
          name: 'clientversion',
          value: '5.5.2'
        }
    ]
```

**i need to merge the name and value from the same certname.**

the outcome needs to be:

```
var endresult= {
  0:{clientcert:"server1", operatingsystem:"windows", operatingsystemmajrelease: "2008 R2", clientversion: 5.5.2}, 
  1:{clientcert:"server2", operatingsystem:"windows", operatingsystemmajrelease: "2008 R2", clientversion: 5.5.2},
  2:{clientcert:"server3", operatingsystem:"RedHat", operatingsystemmajrelease: 6, clientversion: 5.5.2},
};
```

OR

```
{
  clientcert: 'server3',
  operatingsystem: 'windows',
  operatingsystemmajrelease: '2008 R2',
  clientversion: '5.5.2'
},
{
  clientcert: 'server2',
  operatingsystem: 'windows',
  operatingsystemmajrelease: '2008 R2',
  clientversion: '5.5.2'
},
{
  clientcert: 'server1',
  operatingsystem: 'RedHat',
  operatingsystemmajrelease: '6',
  clientversion: '5.5.2'
},
```

I dont know if its easyer to merge back to json format or to JS objects both outcome are fine. :-)
I need this to to merge into an SQL database so i think that JSON is the best outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const json = [{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientcert',value: 'server1'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientcert',value: 'server2'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientcert',value: 'server3'},{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystem',value: 'windows'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystem',value: 'windows'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystem',value: 'RedHat'},{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',value: '2008 R2'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',value: '2008 R2'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',value: '6'},{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientversion',value: '5.5.2'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientversion',value: '5.5.2'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientversion',value: '5.5.2'},];

function format(json){
  const data = json.reduce((a, b) => {
    if(!a[b.certname]) a[b.certname] = {};
    a[b.certname][b.name] = b.value;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(data);
}

console.log(format(json));
```

***EDIT:***
According to the updated question, the input split in a subarrays. To go over it, you can:

- Merge all before go to the above solution, like this:

```js
const json = [[{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientcert',value: 'server1'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientcert',value: 'server2'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientcert',value: 'server3'}],[{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystem',value: 'windows'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystem',value: 'windows'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystem',value: 'RedHat'}],[{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',value: '2008 R2'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',value: '2008 R2'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',value: '6'}],[{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientversion',value: '5.5.2'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientversion',value: '5.5.2'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientversion',value: '5.5.2'}],];

function format(json){
  const data = json.reduce((a,b)=>[...a, ...b], []).reduce((a, b) => {
    if(!a[b.certname]) a[b.certname] = {};
    a[b.certname][b.name] = b.value;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(data);
}

console.log(format(json));
```

- Or iterate over the subarrays inside the `reduce`, like this:

```js
const json = [[{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientcert',value: 'server1'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientcert',value: 'server2'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientcert',value: 'server3'}],[{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystem',value: 'windows'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystem',value: 'windows'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystem',value: 'RedHat'}],[{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',value: '2008 R2'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',value: '2008 R2'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',value: '6'}],[{certname: 'server1',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientversion',value: '5.5.2'},{certname: 'server2',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientversion',value: '5.5.2'},{certname: 'server3',environment: 'acceptance',name: 'clientversion',value: '5.5.2'}],];

function format(json){
  const data = json.reduce((a, b) => {
    b.forEach(t => {
      if(!a[t.certname]) a[t.certname] = {};
      a[t.certname][t.name] = t.value;
    })
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(data);
}

console.log(format(json));
```

Comment: Hi, Jour code workt fine but i did make a mistake my JSON looks a bit different i did edit my post. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
const data = [{
  certname: 'server1',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'clientcert',
  value: 'server1'
},
{
  certname: 'server2',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'clientcert',
  value: 'server2'
},
{
  certname: 'server3',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'clientcert',
  value: 'server3'
},    
{
  certname: 'server1',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'operatingsystem',
  value: 'windows'
},
{
  certname: 'server2',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'operatingsystem',
  value: 'windows'
},
{
  certname: 'server3',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'operatingsystem',
  value: 'RedHat'
},
{
  certname: 'server1',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',
  value: '2008 R2'
},
{
  certname: 'server2',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',
  value: '2008 R2'
},
{
  certname: 'server3',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'operatingsystemmajrelease',
  value: '6'
},
{
  certname: 'server1',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'clientversion',
  value: '5.5.2'
},
{
  certname: 'server2',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'clientversion',
  value: '5.5.2'
},
{
  certname: 'server3',
  environment: 'acceptance',
  name: 'clientversion',
  value: '5.5.2'
}];

const result = {};
data.forEach(val => {
  if(result[val.certname]){
     result[val.certname][val.name] = val.value;
  }else{
    result[val.certname] = {};
    result[val.certname][val.name] = val.value;
  }
})
JSON.stringify(Object.values(result))
```

Comment: Hi, Jour code workt fine but i did make a mistake my JSON looks a bit different i did edit my post. :-)